# TableViewのデータを削除しようとするとアプリが動かなくなる

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, optional

`TableView`のデータを削除しようとすると、何のエラーも表示せずにアプリが動かなくなります。下記のコードのどこがおかしいでしょうか？個人的にオプショナルに関する部分が怪しいかと思っているのですが、具体的にわかりません。。。どなたか不具合の原因が分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

DataViewControllerクラス

```
var nounData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
let dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
nounData.addObjectsFromArray(dbhelper.outputWord("AAA"))    //データベースにあるString型の値が入る

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){            
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        removeData("AAA", wordData: nounData, indexPath: indexPath.row)
    }
}

func removeData(speech: String, wordData: NSMutableArray, indexPath: Int) {
    let dbhelper = DatabaseHelper()
    dbhelper.removeWord(speech, word: (wordData.objectAtIndex(indexPath) as? String)!)
    wordData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
}
```

DatabaseHelperクラス

```
func removeWord(speech: String, word: Optional<String>) {
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.transactionWithBlock( { () -> Void in
        realm.deleteObjects(Word.objectsWhere("speech == %@ AND word == %@", speech, word!))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){            
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        removeData("AAA", wordData: nounData, indexPath: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

上記のメソッドを

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){            
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        removeData("AAA", wordData: nounData, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

に変更することでアプリが動かなくなることがなくなりました。
変更箇所がわかりにくいのですが、`removeData`の第三引数を`indexPath.row`から`indexPath`に変更しました。`removeData`にある

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

のメソッドの第一引数が`indexPath.row`ではなく`indexPath`を取るからでした。
ご回答くださった皆様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

UITableViewからデータを削除する際には、
データソースからの削除だけでなく行の削除自体も行う必要があります。

```
removeData("AAA", wordData: nounData, indexPath: indexPath.row)
```

の後に、

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

が必要となります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りコードを追加してみたのですが、アプリは動かないままでした。。。

Comment: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)` や `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` 内において、データソースから最新のデータを参照するよう実装されていますか？もし一旦メンバ変数にデータを保持し参照するような設計になっていると、削除後のデータの数と行数に不一致が発生しアプリが止まってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

あなたの質問に対する、直接の回答ではありません。提示コードの中に、気になる点があったので、それに対するアドバイスをしたいと思います。

```
var nounData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

Swiftで、配列オブジェクトに、`NS(Mutable)Array`を使うのは、デメリットはあっても、メリットはないに等しいといえます。
`NS(Mutable)Array`は、そのメンバーの型は`AnyObject`（Objective-Cでいえば`id`型）になります。元のオブジェクトがどのような型であっても、メンバーに代入するとき、`AnyObject`に自動でアップキャストされます。しかし、メンバーからオブジェクトを取り出すとき、自動でダウンキャストはしてくれません。手動でダウンキャストしなければいけません。そして、Swiftは型に厳密な言語なので、ダウンキャストに失敗したときの対処をしたプログラムをしないと、コンパイルできません。
「ダウンキャストに失敗したときの対処」とは、具体的には、`as?`を使ってキャストし、ダウンキャストできなかったとき、`nil`を渡すという処理をするのが一般的です。すなわちメンバーから取り出したオブジェクトは、オプショナル型をとります。なお、Swift 1.2より、`as!`というキャストが追加され、強制で非オプショナル型にすることができるようになりました。

```
dbhelper.removeWord(speech, word: (wordData.objectAtIndex(indexPath) as? String)!)
```

これはあなたの提示コードの中の1行ですが、`(wordData.objectAtIndex(indexPath) as? String)!`は、`as!`を使って、`wordData.objectAtIndex(indexPath) as! String`と書き直せるはずです。
Swiftでは、できる限りオプショナル型を使わずに、非オプショナル型の変数だけ使って、プログラムするというのが、ひとつのテクニックになります。配列オブジェクトは、SwiftのArray型を使い、メンバーの型を明示しておくことで、そのメンバーも、メンバから取り出すオブジェクトも、非オプショナル型として取り扱うことができます。

> var nounData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

```
var nounData = [String]()
```

> nounData.addObjectsFromArray(dbhelper.outputWord("AAA"))

```
nounData.extend(dbhelper.outputWord("AAA"))
```

※DatabaseHelperクラスが、配列に関してどういう実装をしているかによって、この記述は変わってきます。

> dbhelper.removeWord(speech, word: (wordData.objectAtIndex(indexPath) as? String)!)

```
dbhelper.removeWord(speech, word: wordData[indexPath])
```

ごらんのように、記述するコード量が、はっきり少なくなるメリットもあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。NSMutableArrayを使うメリットはないに等しいのですね。NSMutableArrayを使おうとしたのには意図があり、nounDataの中身をremoveData()の中で書き換えたかったからで、Swiftの配列は参照型ではないと記事を見たので参照型のNSMutableArrayを使った次第でした。
Swiftではなるべく非オプショナル型の変数を使ってプログラムするというのがテクニックなのですね。今後頭に入れてプログラミングしていこうと思います。